# Stop Chrome from storing background images

Tags: google-chrome

How can I stop chrome from storing my background images. I know chrome does this to allow faster browsing, but when web developing, it is quite annoying. I also don't just want to disable all caching just the part that doesn't refresh background images. Right now every time I change an image, I have to go to settings and remove all cache. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: How do you change the background image? Is the filename (as visible to the browser) the same?

Comment: yes, the file name is the same. Just changing the src file in an image editor.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer is to append a random-number parameter at the end of the file name. The server ignores it but the browser thinks it's not the same file. So, if you have

```
<img src="pic.png" />
```

change it to

```
<img src="pic.png?a=123" />
```

where 123 is a random number generated every time the page loads.

You might even use the MD5 checksum of the file so that the cache is circumvented only when the file has actually changed. This has the added bonus that if you forget to remove the cache-breaker before deploying the site, the users won't be affected by it.

Comment: There are 3 reasons why this is suboptimal.  First, you have to do it for every resource you don't want cached.  Second, you have to UNDO it for all of them once you go into production, or your server will constantly be hammered by requests to download all of these large uncached resources.  Third, you can't mix production and nonproduction.

Comment: Granted, disabling browser cache is the best way but the OP specifically did not want to do it. The checksum method takes care of #2; I don't really understand what you're trying to say with #3.

Comment: I think what he meant was that he didn't want to have to manually delete the cache every time.

Answer (score -1):

Wrench in upper right -> Tools -> Developer Tools -> Gear in lower right -> check "disable cache"